# Toggle slideUp and slideDown on same element

Tags: jquery

When I click on an element it slides associated content down and if I click on another element in the same grid then the associated content slides down for that particular div, hiding the previously clicked on content. This is great but if I click on the same element twice then it does the same thing but I want it to do the opposite. So, if I click on the same element again it should then slideUp instead of repeating the slideDown.

```
$(".g-item").on("click", function () {
    $(".g-item").removeClass('is-active');
    $(this).addClass('is-active');
    $(".g-inner").fadeOut();
    if ($(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
        $(this).parent().find(".is-active [data-grid_content]").slideDown();
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find(".is-active [data-grid_content]").slideUp();
    }
});
```

EDIT:

```
jQuery(".g-item").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("is-active")) {
        $(this).parent().find(".is-active [data-grid_content]").slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass('is-active');

    } else {
        $(this).addClass('is-active');
        jQuery(this).parent().find(".is-active [data-grid_content]").slideDown();
    }
});
```

Comment: Check for `$(this).hasClass("is-active")` at the outset, if it does then stop after g-item.removeClass

Comment: Also: Step through your code.  You have: remove active from all, add to this, then check if this has it.  Well, it always will because you just added it.   If you move/remove `$(this).addClass('is-active');` then it will never have it as the first thing you do is remove it.

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you for your help. I have edited my question and it is working now in the sense that if I click on the same one it slides down and then up, so that toggle is working now! It's just getting the other ones to slide down and slide the current one up now.

Comment: You can re-add your original `$(".g-item").removeClass('is-active');` inside the `else` (and probably the g-inner.fadeOut as well)